# Instantiation fails in a python object

Tags: python, class, instance

I have a little problem with my first experience in python. I'm working on a little game, like labyrinth. I create a class `Map`, when I instantiate it, works. When I tried to instantiate two times the same class I got some problems.

This is the code :

```
from random import randint
class Map:
    """Class that generates map"""
    width = 0
    height = 0
    map = list()
    dictLine = dict()

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """Constructor takes width and height in input"""
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        for i in range(0, self.width * self.height):
            self.map.append('.')
        self.__defineMap()
        self.__defineEntrance()

    def __defineMap(self):
        """Defines Map in a dict"""
        index = 0
        for i in range(0,self.height):
            self.dictLine[index] = self.map[index:index + self.width]
            index = index + self.width

    def printMap(self):
        """Function that prints Wumpus World Map"""
        for i in range(0, self.width * self.height):
            if(i % self.width == 0):
                print()
            print(self.map[i], end='   ')
        print()

    def __defineEntrance(self):
        """Random entrance defined at game start"""
        state = False
        while state is False:
            randomEntrance = randint(0,(self.width * self.height)-1)
            self.map[-self.width:]
            if randomEntrance in range(0,self.width):
                #if entrance is at the first line
                self.map[randomEntrance] = 'E'
                return True
            elif randomEntrance % self.width == 0:
                #if entrance is on the left side
                self.map[randomEntrance] = 'E'
                return True
            for key in self.dictLine.keys():
                #da vedere
                if key + self.width - 1 == randomEntrance:
                    self.map[randomEntrance] = 'E'
                    return True
            l = list()
            for key in self.dictLine.keys():
                l.append(key)
            l.sort()
            l.reverse()
            if randomEntrance in range(l[0], l[0] + self.width):
                self.map[randomEntrance] = 'E'
                return True
        return False

    def reset(self):
        self.__init__(self.width, self.height)
```

This is the result:

```
>>> map = Map(6,6)
>>> map.printMap()

.   .   .   E   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .  

>>> map2 = Map(7,7)
>>> map2.printMap()

.   .   .   E   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   E   .   .   .
```

How can i solve this problem? Thank you all!

Comment: Just keep in mind, calling your class instance ```map``` will overwrite the builtin ```map()``` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first things first.

As [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3047642/max-noel) said, all your variables were created as **class** attribute instead of **instance** so any changes you make in one instance will affect the others (even those you will create). The solution is moving them to `__init__`.

Also, try not to use "reserved" words. `map` is a used as a built-in. Maybe change it to `maze`.

I made some quick changes on your code. There are some room for improvements but it will serve you well:

```
from random import randint


class Maze(object):
    """Class that generates maze"""

    def __init__(self, columns, rows):
        """Constructor takes columns and rows in input"""
        self.columns = columns
        self.rows = rows
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        # Building maze.
        self.__maze_cell_mapping = []
        for i in xrange(self.columns):
            for j in xrange(self.rows):
                self.__maze_cell_mapping.append((i, j))

        # Defining entrance.
        self.__entrance = None
        self.__define_entrance()

    def __define_entrance(self):
        """Random entrance defined at game start"""
        while self.__entrance is None:
            cell_id = randint(0, len(self.__maze_cell_mapping))
            if self.__is_boundary(cell_id):
                self.__entrance = self.__maze_cell_mapping[cell_id]

    def __is_boundary(self, cell_id):
        """
        :param int cell_id:
            ID of the cell to check.

        :rtype: bool
        :returns:
            ``True`` if given ``cell_id`` is at maze boundary.
        """
        column, row = self.__maze_cell_mapping[cell_id]
        if column == 0 or column == self.columns - 1:
            return True
        elif row == 0 or row == self.rows - 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def print_maze(self):
        """Function that prints Wumpus World Maze"""
        result = [
            ['.'] * self.columns
            for _i in xrange(self.rows)
        ]

        column, row = self.__entrance
        result[column][row] = 'E'

        for row in result:
            print('   '.join(row))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

`map` is a class attribute (shared between all instances of the class), not an instance attribute.

If that's not the behavior you want, change it so that it's an instance attribute -- that is, move the `map = list()` part to inside `__init__`. You'll probably want to do the same to `width`, `height` and `dictLine`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to move map=list() inside the Constructor, but a new problem was there :
>>> from map import *
>>> mappa = Map(5,5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Marco/Desktop/Wumpus World/map.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.map.append('.')
AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: Your traceback indicates that you're trying to append things to `self.map` before declaring it (seriously, *read the error messages*). Make sure the definition is at the very top of `__init__`.